# No module named 'automl' when unpickle auto-trained model

Tags: python, pickle, azure-machine-learning-service, automl

I'm trying to reproduce 2 tutorials below using my own dataset instead of MNIST dataset.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-auto-train-models
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-deploy-models-with-aml

About
'/notebooks/tutorials/03.auto-train-models.ipynb'
there's no problem. I've got 'model.pkl'.

However, 
'/notebooks/tutorials/02.deploy-models.ipynb'
has an error below in 'Predict test data' cell.
I guess it's a matter of 'pickle' and 'import'.

Tell me solutions, please.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-11cf888b622f> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.externals import joblib
      3 
----> 4 clf = joblib.load('./model.pkl')
      5 # clf = joblib.load('./sklearn_mnist_model.pkl')
      6 y_hat = clf.predict(X_test)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    576                     return load_compatibility(fobj)
    577 
--> 578                 obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    579 
    580     return obj

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    506     obj = None
    507     try:
--> 508         obj = unpickler.load()
    509         if unpickler.compat_mode:
    510             warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in load(self)
   1048                     raise EOFError
   1049                 assert isinstance(key, bytes_types)
-> 1050                 dispatch[key[0]](self)
   1051         except _Stop as stopinst:
   1052             return stopinst.value

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in load_global(self)
   1336         module = self.readline()[:-1].decode("utf-8")
   1337         name = self.readline()[:-1].decode("utf-8")
-> 1338         klass = self.find_class(module, name)
   1339         self.append(klass)
   1340     dispatch[GLOBAL[0]] = load_global

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in find_class(self, module, name)
   1386             elif module in _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING:
   1387                 module = _compat_pickle.IMPORT_MAPPING[module]
-> 1388         __import__(module, level=0)
   1389         if self.proto >= 4:
   1390             return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'automl'
```

Comment: it works. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to include azureml-train-automl package. and you have to do this:

import azureml.train.automl

Comment: this works -- not so obvious when you unpickle that you need the import!

Comment: 2023 this doesn't seem to work anymore, the azureml.train library is no longer recognized

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you don't have the `automl` python package installed. It is possible to import it by `import azureml.train.automl`, but you should really install it using pip.

Follow the guide on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/quickstart-create-workspace-with-python) to see how to set up your python environment for Azure ML services.

For most use cases `notebook` and `automl` are the only extra packages needed, so the command

`pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk[notebooks,automl]`

should be sufficient.

Use `pip list` to see all installed packages and version number. You should see `azureml-train-automl` if the package is installed correctly.

Comment: How would you install these extra packages using an environment.yml file? Can you just have an entry with - azureml-sdk[automl]

Comment: @IvoMerchiers (I know, I am a year late with my answer, but better late than sorry), I do not have that much experience with .yml files, so I'm not really sure how this would work. I suggest you play around a little, and see what works.

Comment: 2023 this doesn't seem to work anymore, the azureml.train library is no longer recognized